# Reciprocal vlookup function- help converting from VBA to google sheets App script

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets, vlookup

I am fairly unfamiliar with both VBA and especially google sheets App Scripts.

That being said I was able to google enough yesterday to figure out what I wanted to achieve in VBA. TO make sharing my spreadsheet easier i wanted to try and convert it to google sheets. I've figured out most of it, except for this particular section.

Here is the main sheet (only one people need to see). In excel, people can paste data (in the right format) into the orange input field in column B and it splits the text into the yellow fields below it.

[image: Main Sheet]

The fields in column C are automatically updated based on a vlookup to several reference sheets using the key in column B.

[image: Example reference sheet]

From here I am able to edit column B or C and the other is updated to keep them in sync. I had to duplicate column A into column C in the reference sheets as vlookup only works left to right and i couldn't get xlookup working.

Here is the sloppy VBA code I have working. I'm sure it is a mess, but it works perfectly for what I needed

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
    If Len("B2") > 1 Then
        Dim regex As Object
        Dim X As Variant
        Dim Y As Variant
        Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        regex.Pattern = "font[0-9]{1,2}="
        Y = Replace(Range("B2").Value, "(", "")
        Y = Replace(Y, ")", "")
        Y = regex.Replace(Y, "")
        X = Split(Y, ",")
        Range("B3").Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(X)
        Range("C6").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B6"), Sheets("A (Hum)").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
        Range("C7").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B7"), Sheets("B (Blaster)").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
        Range("C8").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B8"), Sheets("C (Force)").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
        Range("C9").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B9"), Sheets("D (Lockup)").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
        Range("C10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B10"), Sheets("E (FoC)").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
        Range("C11").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B11"), Sheets("F (Ignition)").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
    End If
End If

'Stop the reciprocal vlookups causing an error
Application.EnableEvents = False

' IF Column B is selected, changed column C
If Target.Address = "$B$6" Then
    Range("C6").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B6"), Sheets("A (Hum)").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$7" Then
    Range("C7").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B7"), Sheets("B (Blaster)").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$8" Then
    Range("C8").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B8"), Sheets("C (Force)").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$9" Then
    Range("C9").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B9"), Sheets("D (Lockup)").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$10" Then
    Range("C10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B10"), Sheets("E (FoC)").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
End If
If Target.Address = "$B$11" Then
    Range("C11").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B11"), Sheets("F (Ignition)").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
End If

' And Vice Versa
If Target.Address = "$C$6" Then
    Range("B6").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("C6"), Sheets("A (Hum)").Range("B:C"), 2, 0)
End If
If Target.Address = "$C$7" Then
    Range("B7").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("C7"), Sheets("B (Blaster)").Range("B:C"), 2, 0)
End If
If Target.Address = "$C$8" Then
    Range("B8").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("C8"), Sheets("C (Force)").Range("B:C"), 2, 0)
End If
If Target.Address = "$C$9" Then
    Range("B9").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("C9"), Sheets("D (Lockup)").Range("B:C"), 2, 0)
End If
If Target.Address = "$C$10" Then
    Range("B10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("C10"), Sheets("E (FoC)").Range("B:C"), 2, 0)
End If
If Target.Address = "$C$11" Then
    Range("B11").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("C11"), Sheets("F (Ignition)").Range("B:C"), 2, 0)
End If

'Re-enable events after updates
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, converting code from one language to another is considered out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Only for the sake of having an answer for anyone else googling I do have it working. Definitely can be refined but the first iteration of it working in the same way is below. Not nearly as instant as excel, but functionally the same

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B2') {
    var input = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2').getValue();
    if (input.length > 0) {
      var regex = new RegExp('font[0-9]{1,2}=');
      var input = input.replace(regex,"");
      var input = input.replace("(","");
      var input = input.replace(")","");
      var array = input.split(',');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B3").setValue(array[0]);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B4").setValue(array[1]);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B5").setValue(array[2]);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B6").setValue(array[3]);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B7").setValue(array[4]);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B8").setValue(array[5]);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B9").setValue(array[6]);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B10").setValue(array[7]);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B11").setValue(array[8]);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B12").setValue(array[9]);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B13").setValue(array[10]);

      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C6").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("A (Hum)").getRange('A:B').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("A (Hum)").getRange('A:B').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B6").getValue())][1]);

      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C7").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("B (Blaster)").getRange('A:B').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("B (Blaster)").getRange('A:B').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B7").getValue())][1]);

      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C8").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("C (Force)").getRange('A:B').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("C (Force)").getRange('A:B').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B8").getValue())][1]);

      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C9").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("D (Lockup)").getRange('A:B').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("D (Lockup)").getRange('A:B').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B9").getValue())][1]);

      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C10").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("E (FoC)").getRange('A:B').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("E (FoC)").getRange('A:B').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B10").getValue())][1]);

      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C11").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("F (Ignition)").getRange('A:B').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("F (Ignition)").getRange('A:B').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B11").getValue())][1]);

      
    }  
  }

  /* A (Hum) */
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B6') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C6").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("A (Hum)").getRange('A:B').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("A (Hum)").getRange('A:B').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B6").getValue())][1]);
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C6') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B6").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("A (Hum)").getRange('B:C').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("A (Hum)").getRange('B:C').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("C6").getValue())][1]);
  }
  /* B (Blaster) */
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B7') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C7").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("B (Blaster)").getRange('A:B').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("B (Blaster)").getRange('A:B').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B7").getValue())][1]);
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C7') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B7").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("B (Blaster)").getRange('B:C').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("B (Blaster)").getRange('B:C').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("C7").getValue())][1]);
  }

  /* C (Force) */
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B8') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C8").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("C (Force)").getRange('A:B').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("C (Force)").getRange('A:B').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B8").getValue())][1]);
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C8') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B8").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("C (Force)").getRange('B:C').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("C (Force)").getRange('B:C').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("C8").getValue())][1]);
  }

  /* D (Lockup) */
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B9') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C9").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("D (Lockup)").getRange('A:B').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("D (Lockup)").getRange('A:B').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B9").getValue())][1]);
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C9') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B9").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("D (Lockup)").getRange('B:C').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("D (Lockup)").getRange('B:C').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("C9").getValue())][1]);
  }

  /* E (FoC) */
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B10') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C10").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("E (FoC)").getRange('A:B').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("E (FoC)").getRange('A:B').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B10").getValue())][1]);
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C10') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B10").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("E (FoC)").getRange('B:C').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("E (FoC)").getRange('B:C').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("C10").getValue())][1]);
  }

  /* F (Ignition) */
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B11') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C11").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("F (Ignition)").getRange('A:B').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("F (Ignition)").getRange('A:B').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B11").getValue())][1]);
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C11') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B11").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("F (Ignition)").getRange('B:C').getValues()[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("F (Ignition)").getRange('B:C').getValues().map(x => x[0]).indexOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("C11").getValue())][1]);
  }


}
```